# Tracking wandering vulnerable adults

Tags: rfid, gps

I work in the field of telecare and advances are helping us keep the elderly and vulnerable out of residential homes/hospitals and allowing to retain their dignity and independence by staying in their own home.

The one thing that is missing in my "arsenal" of equipment is a sensor that will track when the wearer moves out of the property or range of the central control unit.  Kind of like the prisoner tag systems, but less intrusive.  Obviously I don't want to tag the elderly and this would only ever be used with consent.  I would also like the option of many tags being monitored as we couldn't always guarantee that they would take their phone, keys or bag (or clothes sometimes!)  Ideally the "tags" could be small enough to be sewn into clothing or added to small bracelets or chains.

I've looked into RFID but the range or cost always becomes an option.  What other things can I look at to help?  GPS would be great to find the wanderer but again size of the "tag" would become an issue.

Answer (score 3):

We actually did a lot of research on implementing a system like this for our elderly customers.  The problem with any tag based system is the same problem with any PERS system (I've fallen etc...).  The problem is most people just won't wear the tags / monitoring bracelets.   The closest thing we came up that might work would be having the family sew small tags into all their pants, or using the small space in a nike shoe where they keep their Nike+ hardware to store a xcvr.  We also looked into using watches, but what we needed were nice metal watches not the plastic timex style ones that were available with xcvrs in them.   Oh and there was talk of planting something in walkers and canes, if someone needs that to get around you could do it I guess.

There were plenty of meetings with talk about "social contracts" between the eldery caree and the caregiver where they would agree to use the tags but it was BS because the elderly were just not interested.

In the end we settled on a more complicated version of what you describe.  Motion sensors throughout the house that communicate to our backend servers.  There we process daily living patterns to determine if anything might be up.  Has no one opened the fridge at 8AM, bathroom not used in last 4 hours but should have been, etc.  Combining multiple sources seemed the way to go.

However that wasn't even the final solution for our customers.  The expense of installing and configuring all those sensors is a pain in the...   So our final solution is a touch screen system that the elderly use to check in on every day.  The software and UI was designed specifically for an elderly user, and has things to check on medicine usage, are they ok.  But it also implements a family section as well, with pictures, games, activities, video chat, email, web and a lot more.   All designed for elederly non computer users.

This ended up engaging the elderly person a lot more, and we were able to take all of that information into our backend where the family or pro caregiver could see how they were doing. If someone fell we might not know right away but we'd know when they missed their next checkin. So not exactly what you're asking for but I thought I'd share our experience and see if it helped you out.

Comment: I love the social engineering idea. That gets you all the info you need and the client doesn't think twice about it, just goes about their daily chores. I think Axis Camera systems have WiFi networked sensors/cameras that would reduce the installation costs. Probably some other mfg too I'm just familiar with Axis.

Comment: Thanks :) we have elderly folks who've been using it for a few years now and they love it.  I'm a fan of Axis Camera's to, I did a tear down on a bunch of different brands and there's was the best by far.  Optics were just way better for one.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO cameras are the way to go. A well build camera system with internet connection could do a lot more than just tracking. You can check the status in case emergencies, detect falls etc.

Comment: We have implemented cameras in a few instances however our service, which covers a fairly small geographic area, has almost 2,000 clients so 24/7 surveillance would be impractical.

One solution we have is to have door contacts that start an internal timer going and if movement is not detected within the property (usually via PIR) within x minutes then alarm will be raised. However this system is less than ideal as we get a ton of false alarms as it doesn't allow clients to spend time in their gardens or will raise alarms if they are talking to someone on the doorstep for example.